# Unable to remove polyline when another marker in google map is clicked

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-polyline

I am working on google map where i am using google map api to add multiple markers on the google map for ATMs .It means i have multiple markers corresponding to ATMs in my google map.When i click on a marker,a polyline is drawn between my current location and marker.When i click on another marker ,a new polyline is drawn but the previous one is not deleted.Please find below my code:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String parseData) {
    super.onPostExecute(parseData);
    dialog.dismiss();
    //map.clear();
    ArrayList<LatLng> allpooints = CommonUtility.decodePoly(parseData);
    if(prevPolyLine!=null) {
        prevPolyLine.remove();
        //map.clear();
        Log.e(" ","polyline");
        PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions();
        options.width(7);
        options.color(Color.BLUE);
        options.geodesic(true);
        options.visible(true);
        for (LatLng temp : allpooints) {
            options.add(temp);
        }

        prevPolyLine = map.addPolyline(options);
        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        for (LatLng latLng : allpooints) {
            builder.include(latLng);
        }
        final LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
        //BOUND_PADDING is an int to specify padding of bound.. try 100.
        CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 20);
        map.animateCamera(cu);
    }else{
        Log.e("polylineTAG","----------------------");
        PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions();
        options.width(7);
        options.color(Color.BLUE);
        options.geodesic(true);
        options.visible(true);
        for (LatLng temp : allpooints) {
            options.add(temp);
        }

        prevPolyLine = map.addPolyline(options);
        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        for (LatLng latLng : allpooints) {
            builder.include(latLng);
        }
        final LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
        //BOUND_PADDING is an int to specify padding of bound.. try 100.
        CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 20);
        map.animateCamera(cu);

    }

}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nk9w6.png)

Please help me to fix the issue.I want to remove polyline drawn between my current location and previous marker,when i click on new marker in the map.

Comment: have you implemented the onMarkerClickListener?

Comment: other than the clicked ATM loc and your position,are there other markers you need to show?

Comment: yes i have implemented onMarkerClickListener.                                             yes actually am showing the availabe ATM's within a particular range and  i want that when am clicking on some other marker for direction then the previous polyline drawn should get erased so that i can get the direction of newly clicked marker from my current location

Comment: how bout puting the marker adds to a function,then after the onclick listener,do map.clear() to remove the polyline,then call the marker adding function again?

Comment: i have tried this ..that after clicking on the marker ,am clearing the map and then adding the marker again .but with this idea am only able to add that particular marker only which has been clicked . And now one more problem is arising that when am clicking on some other category like Hotel other than ATM then last marker of ATM which has been clicked remains there with the poly line until i clicked direction for some other marker .